# How do I input multiple positive numbers

Tags: input, numbers, output

I am pretty new to Python and I have tried many times now but I dont seem to be able to code this right.
I try to make a program where I can input multiple positive numbers. I seem to have understood the abs()function, but I have probelms with adding more than one number in my input.

This is the code I have tried.

**n=int(input("Skriv inn noen tall: "))

print(n)

x=abs(n)

print(x)**

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: read in a string of space-separated numbers (example: `-1 -2 -3 -4- 5`), call `split` on this string to separate out the numbers, iterate through the list of split numbers and cast each one to an int and call `abs` on the number as well.

```
input_nums = input("Skriv inn noen tall: ").split(' ')
nums = [abs(int(num)) for num in input_nums]
print(nums)
```

Output (for input: `-1 -2 -3 -4- 5`)

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```